# Freeze Title Header in gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, freeze

I have a Title in my webpage, some texts,a textbox and a button. I have a large gridview that needs to be scrolled vertically and horizontally. What i want is, Even if I scroll the gridview, the Title in my webpage, some texts,a textbox and a button will still be in the same position or freeze.

here is my html code

```
  <div>
Data Warehouse Calendar Maintenance

    <br />
    <br />

</div>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Date:"></asp:Label>

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_View" runat="server" onclick="btn_View_Click" Text="View" />
</p>
<p>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
        BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="5" Font-Names="Calibri" 
        Font-Size="Medium" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="Black" 
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="271px">
        <RowStyle Wrap="False" />
        <EmptyDataRowStyle Wrap="False" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" 
            Wrap="False" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="False" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" 
            Wrap="False"/>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" 
            Wrap="False" />
        <EditRowStyle Wrap="False" />

        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" Wrap="False" />

    </asp:GridView>

</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do it very easily by using css. css has the property for postion. So set your postion fixed like this.

```
.Title
{
Position:Fixed;
Top:120px; // Set as per your requirement
Left:120px; // Set as per your requirement
}
```

apply title class to that Title div.

Same can be written for  texts, Textbox and for button.

Comment: First write this css class somewhere ie. on your page or in your css file and apply to div like this - <div class="Title">Data Warehouse Calendar Maintenance</div>

Comment: I did like this : <div class="title">
   &nbsp;Data Warehouse Calendar Maintenance
      .title
      {
      Position:Fixed;
    Top:120px; 
    Left:120px;
      }
        <br />
        <br />
        
    </div>

but its wrong

Comment: oh you didn't write css correctly on your page. You should write it on Head section of the page like this   
<style type="text/css">
    .Title
{
Position:Fixed;
Top:120px; // Set as per your requirement
Left:120px; // Set as per your requirement
} 
    </style>

Comment: how can I insert it here? it gives me error 

 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Date:"></asp:Label>

Comment: you can use it like  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="Title" Text="Enter Date:"></asp:Label>

Answer (score 1):

Refer this sample http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Scrollable-GridView-with-Fixed-Headers-in-ASP.Net.aspx
It will be useful to your problem.

Comment: i dont want columns to freeze.